# Is it possible to tell if a unjailbroken phone has been jailbroken in the past?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I heard that a phone can be jailbroken and then "un-jailbroken." Is it possible to tell if an "un-jailbroken" phone has been jailbroken in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the device has been restored(how you "unjailbreak" a device), there is no way to find out if the device has been jailbroken in the past.

Comment: When you say restored, do you mean a factory restore? Like on an iPhone, you would go to Settings, and there's some option called "Restore all settings and iPhone"

Comment: @lamanon Yes, except it is usually done through iTunes(https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iphone/unjailbreak-your-iphone-3601679/).